# only one session variable stored in php

Tags: php, session

I'm started to work with php on a Windows Server 2008 and with a dataconnection to a MS SQL SERVER. Now in the past I did it on apache and mysql. But now I have changed, my session variables are not working anymore. Only one session variable is stored in my session files on the server. While I have multiple session variables over multiple files. The only line which is stored is the following:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["language"])){$_SESSION["language"] = 
substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);}
```

in my file:

**language|s:2:"nl";**

When I go on and login to my application I store the following session variables:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params,$options);
$numrows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
if ($numrows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin']= TRUE;
    $_SESSION['username']= $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['name']= $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['language']= $row['language'];
    //if ($row['admin'] == 1){$_SESSION['admin']= TRUE;}
    //if ($row['all_orders'] == 1){$_SESSION['allorders']= TRUE;}
    //if ($row['validate'] == 1){$_SESSION['validate'] = TRUE;}
    echo 'Welcome '.strtoupper(trim($_SESSION['name']));    }
else {
    echo 'Login niet correct '.$username.' '.$password; };
```

But in the file I cannot find these session variables. They are not stored anywhere so I cannot call them on my other pages. Anyone got an idea.

Comment: Just to double check, you are using session_start() right?

Comment: check if $numrows > 0 really satifies and the control goes in the if block..

Comment: And also, to double check, did you try some var_dump() to see if your content are actually filled up? (what does var_dump($row['username']) display?)

Comment: delete the file and re-do the script, to see if its re-created. (I assume this is in the servers directory that stores the session files and its not DB based sessions)

Comment: Also check the session ids used. If there is some problem with passing the session id (cookie), then you might be writing to different session files.

Comment: $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params,$options);
$numrows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);//these function may contains bug in order to sort out bug we need of these function to understand

Comment: @AnkurSaxena Those are PHP functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php

Comment: okey jim i'm not aware of that i'm also a learner.is we get $numrows

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();//session_start — Start new or resume existing session 
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params,$options);
$numrows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
if ($numrows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin']= TRUE;
    $_SESSION['username']= $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['name']= $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['language']= $row['language'];
    //if ($row['admin'] == 1){$_SESSION['admin']= TRUE;}
    //if ($row['all_orders'] == 1){$_SESSION['allorders']= TRUE;}
    //if ($row['validate'] == 1){$_SESSION['validate'] = TRUE;}
    echo 'Welcome '.strtoupper(trim($_SESSION['name']));    }
else {
    echo 'Login niet correct '.$username.' '.$password; };
```

if you are getting  if ($numrows > 0){ return TRUE;} then it must be due to session_start(); you unable to store session value.